# PayPal, how can I know about user doing after click pay?

Tags: php, paypal, notifications, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt

I'm developing a site and it has a problem. I'm trying to add PayPal to my site, but I've encountered a problem. I use ipn and pdt, but that does not solve my problem. 
What's the problem?
When a user clicks "PayPal button" in my site, he is redirected to PayPal payment page. And then he can pay or can return to my site.
If he clicks "Pay", he's redirected after 10 seconds. But if he clicks "Back" before 10 seconds or closes tab, my site does not get quick notifications. Site gets IPN notification, but slowly. IPN can send me notification after long time, but I need to get user info about the payment status (pending) quickly to show user about the payment processing. After this, I get ipn and change status to the complete. But what am I doing wrong in this situation?
How to get information immediately after payment?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal IPN is an instant notification, you will get the IPN immediately after the payment completes. If you are seeing any delays in IPN receiving kindly connect with PayPal support team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com for further help.